# Embedding SQL Server Compact 3.5 in the application

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

I am confused about embedding the sql server compact 3.5 files in my application.
I have included 7 files in the setup but application fails to run on some computers.

Is there some version problem?

I wish to embed both (32 & 64 bit) as I do not know the target platform.
How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Compact is deprecated. Strongly recommend you look into Express and/or LocalDB.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to build for x86 and only include the x86 dll files in the project folder. 
If you are using raw ADO.NET, you may be able to make Any CPU Work, if you follow the many steps in my blog post here, but I do not recommend this: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html